# Gforth can't find script it's supposed to start

Tags: linux, gforth

I tried to execute a cgi script written in Gforth through the terminal by `./myscript.cgi`, however it throws an error: No such file or directory. Executing the same code as a .fs file throws the same error message-text. I believe the problem is that Gforth fails to open the file.

I'm running Arch Linux and had to install Gforth through snapd. The Gforth binary/executable thus lies in `var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/gforth` which I found out through `$ whereis gforth`.

Simplifying the problem: I'm trying to execute a `test.fs` file with Gforth with `$ gforth /path/to/file` in the terminal, however not successful:

```
$ gforth /srv/http/cgi-bin/mytest.fs

*in file included from *the terminal*:0:-94635140744367:
*the terminal*:-1:1: error: No such file or directory
>>>/srv/http/cgi-bin/mytest.fs<<<
Backtrace:
...*
```

[image: The image shows the backtrace of the error message. The trace points to files inside the directory /snap/gforth/27/usr/share/gforth/0.7.9_20230130/...]

However the file directory is correct.

The [Gforth documentation](https://gforth.org/manual/Using-files-for-Forth-code-Tutorial.html) looks like:

> You can easily start Gforth with some files loaded like this:
>
> > gforth file1.fs file2.fs

so I think I am typing the correct command. And all permissions for the file are given.

The test script in gforth looks as following - nothing complicated

```
." Hello World"
bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deinstalling snapd Gforth and reinstalling it via Arch AUR seems to be the solution. Thus your problem was that Gforth wasn't correctly installed.

To install AUR packages you should see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_User_Repository) and this is the [Gforth package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gforth)

First create a build directory. I created mine under `/home/<user>/builds` (creating dir by `$ mkdir <dirname>`) and than in there download Gforth by `$ git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/gforth.git`.

Check if you have permissions for that folder by `$ ls -al` and looking for `gforth`. Here is a [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/File_permissions_and_attributes). If not all users have write permissions do: `$ chmod o=rwx gforth`.

Go into Gforth (`$ cd gforth`) and build the package by `$ makepkg -si`.

After following the installation, Gforth should run correct. Try it out with `$ gforth` and you should be welcomed by the gforth terminal.